# The subprocess.call() function is not working

Tags: python, subprocess, method-call

I was doing an exersize with the following task:
Write a python program to call an external command in Python.

As I could not solve it by my own I looked up the solution:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ls", "-l"])
```

But the solution threw an Error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

I also tried adding shell=True and for example leaving out the brackets like following:

```
subprocess.call('ls -l', shell=True)
```

In this case it tells me that the command "ls" could not be found.

I am working on windows 10,Python 3.8.2 32 bit

I am kind of lost and would be glad if someone could help.

Thank you!

Comment: Open on Windows your command line interface and write `ls`.

Comment: but the problem is I need to use python for it.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work either. :(

Comment: That's the issue. Your python code is working. The `ls` command does not exist on Windows.

Comment: I suggest checking the environment used for the tutorial you're using before going forward, and maybe installing a virtual environment that would emulate that environment. The tutorial seem to expect a Linux environment, and other issues might arise in the future

Answer (score 2):

`ls` is not a valid Windows CMD command.
For learning purpose, you may try `CD` for printing current directory, ie

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['CD'], shell=True)
```

Comment: or `dir` to get behaviour fairly similar to `ls`